# What is the difference b/w add class condition by the help of *ngIf and [ngClass]?

Tags: angular, mean-stack

What is the difference between code 1 and code 2

**1**

```
<mat-sidenav *ngIf="menuClicked" class="col-3 pl-0" mode="side" fixedTopGap="56" opened="true">
    <report-sidebar [isIconShow]="menuClicked"></report-sidebar>
</mat-sidenav>
<mat-sidenav *ngIf="!menuClicked" class="col-1 pl-0" mode="side" fixedTopGap="56" opened="true">
    <report-sidebar [isIconShow]="menuClicked"></report-sidebar>
</mat-sidenav>
```

and

**2**

````
<mat-sidenav class="pl-0" [ngClass]="menuClicked?'col-3':'col-1'" mode="side" fixedTopGap="56" opened="true">
    <report-sidebar [isIconShow]="menuClicked"></report-sidebar>
</mat-sidenav>```
````

Comment: What are you wanting from this?

Answer (score 0):

I've not used that method personally but you can use this in your use case

```
<mat-sidenav
    class="pl-0"
    [class.col-3]="menuClicked"
    [class.col-1]="!menuClicked"
    ...>
    <report-sidebar [isIconShow]="menuClicked"></report-sidebar>
</mat-sidenav>
```

Answer (score 0):

For code1 ***ngIf="menuClicked"**,

Let me assign `menuClicked = true;`
If menuClicked value is false,  the whole mat-sidenav don't display. I mean the following code not displayed in html.

```
<mat-sidenav *ngIf="menuClicked" class="col-3 pl-0" mode="side" fixedTopGap="56" opened="true">
    <report-sidebar [isIconShow]="menuClicked"></report-sidebar>
</mat-sidenav>
```

And the following code worked.

```
<mat-sidenav *ngIf="!menuClicked" class="col-1 pl-0" mode="side" fixedTopGap="56" opened="true">
    <report-sidebar [isIconShow]="menuClicked"></report-sidebar>
</mat-sidenav>
```

For code2 **[ngClass]="menuClicked?'col-3':'col-1'"**,

It change class value only depends on **menuClicked value**.
I mean if menuClicked value is true, class has col-3 property.

```
<mat-sidenav class="pl-0 col-3" mode="side" fixedTopGap="56" opened="true">
    <report-sidebar [isIconShow]="menuClicked"></report-sidebar>
</mat-sidenav>
```

If menuClicked value is false, class has col-1 property.

```
<mat-sidenav class="pl-0 col-1" mode="side" fixedTopGap="56" opened="true">
    <report-sidebar [isIconShow]="menuClicked"></report-sidebar>
</mat-sidenav>
```

The main difference of your code for *ngIf and [ngClass] is that *ngIf work for the whole html tag to display or not and [ngClass] only change class property base on condition.

Comment: Will there be a difference in their results?  because they give me different results. code 1 gives different and code 2 also give different results.

Comment: Yes, *ngIf can change the whole container to display or not without adding no CSS.  For [ngClass], it only change which css work base on its condition.

Comment: I mean that difference in the View or page on screen!

Comment: Oh! , I told about that. Please read carefully.